# Значение столбца в список Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas, таблица. У меня есть значения в столбце **'industry_type'**

[image: Кусочек таблицы]

Я хочу преобразовать их, чтобы они разбились на:

*['Banking',  'E-Commerce',  'Internet',  'Mobile',  'Telecommunications']*

для каждого **'organizationID'** соответственно, но не знаю как это сделать.

Для начала я удалила запятые, использовав:

```
cols = ['industry_type']
for col in cols: 
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',', ' ')
```

Получила следующее:

[image: значения без запятых]

Чтобы преобразовать в строку столбец **'industry_type'** использовала:

```
list_indus = df['industry_type'].tolist()
```

Но в результате получаю:

*['Banking  E-Commerce  Internet  Mobile  Telecommunications', 'Advertising  Internet  Online Games  Online Portals  Social Media Marketing',...*

Только начинаю программировать и работать с pandas, подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, может цикл какой...

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: "_подскажите пожалуйста, что нужно сделать_" чтобы вам подсказали, для начала, отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавьте в него фрагмент ваших данных в воспроизводимом виде и пример того, что вы хотите увидеть в результате.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно конечно, что вы хотите.

```
dict_of = {"org_id": [1, 2, 3],
     "org_name": ['bank1', 'bank2', 'bank3'],
     'in_type': [['Banking', 'E-Commerce', 'Internet', 'Mobile', 'Telecommunications'], ...]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_of)

>>> 
   org_id org_name                                            in_type
0       1    bank1  [Banking, E-Commerce, Internet, Mobile, Teleco...
1       2    bank2  [Banking, E-Commerce, Internet, Mobile, Teleco...
2       3    bank3  [Banking, E-Commerce, Internet, Mobile, Teleco...
```

**Вариант 1**

```
>>> print(df.explode('in_type'))

   org_id org_name             in_type
0       1    bank1             Banking
0       1    bank1          E-Commerce
0       1    bank1            Internet
0       1    bank1              Mobile
0       1    bank1  Telecommunications
1       2    bank2             Banking
1       2    bank2          E-Commerce
1       2    bank2            Internet
1       2    bank2              Mobile
1       2    bank2  Telecommunications
2       3    bank3             Banking
2       3    bank3          E-Commerce
2       3    bank3            Internet
2       3    bank3              Mobile
2       3    bank3  Telecommunications
```

**Вариант 2**

```
>>> print(df.merge(df.in_type.apply(pd.Series), right_index=True, left_index=True))


   org_id org_name        0           1         2       3                   4
0       1    bank1  Banking  E-Commerce  Internet  Mobile  Telecommunications
1       2    bank2  Banking  E-Commerce  Internet  Mobile  Telecommunications
2       3    bank3  Banking  E-Commerce  Internet  Mobile  Telecommunications
```

*А может и вообще совсем другое :)*

**UPD**

```
df['in_type'] = df['in_type'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))

>>> df
   org_id org_name                                            in_type
0       1    bank1  [Banking, E-Commerce, Internet, Mobile, Teleco...
1       2    bank2  [Banking, E-Commerce, Internet, Mobile, Teleco..
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за решение, но имела в виду другое :)
У меня 900 строк и я хотела именно слова в столбце industry_type преобразовать в список, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было их вычленять и анализировать по типам

Comment: @OlgaOtinova Видимо так?

Answer (score 1):

Предположим, есть датафрейм:

```
   moo  org industry_type
0   11    1       a, b, c
1   22    2           foo
2   33    3           bar
```

```
res = df["industry_type"].str.split(",").explode().str.strip().to_frame().combine_first(df)
```

res:

```
  industry_type  moo  org
0             a   11    1
0             b   11    1
0             c   11    1
1           foo   22    2
2           bar   33    3
```